# Filtering empty cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, cell-format, microsoft-excel-365

Notice that `B2` and `B3` are merged and a filter is created on the `B` column

[image]

When I'm going to apply the filter it shows `Empty` (`Vazias` in Portuguese) as one of the options as there are merged cells in the column:

[image]

The problem is that when I filter on `Yes` it filters out `line 3` which is part of the result I want:

[image]

How to eliminate the `Empty` filter option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright just to let you know, merged cells are a nightmare. A proper dataset wouldn't have merged cells. The minute you merge cells together, it will delete the values from the second, third or whichever cell in the merged range.

One simple way I demonstrated in my initial comment is to simply use a helper column:

[image]

The formula used in `C2`:

```
=IF(B2="",C1,B2)
```

Drag down and simply filter on that column.

---

The long workaround would be to:

- Select column B, copy paste it to an empty column
- Select column B, unmerge all cells
- With all cells selected, go to `Find & Select` > `Go To Special` > Choose `Blanks` option under Select section
- Type `=` and hit the <kbd>↑</kbd> key
- Confirm through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
- Select column B again, this time copy/paste onto column B as values (to get rid of the formulas)
- Select the column where you temporarily pasted column B in the first step
- Right click on `B1` > `Paste Special` > Choose `Format`
- Remove the temporary column

Now you can filter on the merged cells

[image]

Comment: Both ways work. Right now I tend to prefer the long one as the sheet will be used by others and it shows one only formatted column.